# Toogle div based on span class value

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have the following block

```
<div id="discountText">
    <span>some text</span>
    <span class="discountType" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

`installerDiscountType` contains a discount type (preferred, saved, etc.)

How do I show the `div` in case `<span class="discountType"` equals "AAA" and hide it in case it equals something else?

I tried multiple ways but I keep getting undefined values.

Comment: is "AAA" a class or the text in the span?

Comment: @BrianMcCall the text. So if I remove the `style="display:none;"` part, it outputs "AAA".

Answer (score 1):

This will show "Some Text AAA" It shows "Some Text" because that span does not have class "discountType"

```
let types = document.querySelectorAll('.discountType')
types.forEach(node => {
  if(node.innerText !== "AAA") {
    node.style.display = 'none';
  }
})

<div id="discountText">
  <span>some text</span>
  <span class="discountType">Hello world</span>
  <span class="discountType">AAA</span>
</div>
```

Comment: When I put `alert(node.innerText);` above the `if` statement it says it is empty.

Comment: I think it hides the `span`, not the `div` though, right?

Comment: yeah it hides the span. If you want to hide the div. Change it to document.getElementById('discountText').style.display = 'none'

Comment: I think I see what the issue is. `<span class="discountType">` does not work, but `<span class="discountType">AAA</span` does. I wonder how I can actually extract the text within the `span class` to make it work.